# jwplayer javascript embed loading localhost:3000/undefined

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm trying to load jwplayer content into a lightbox using Javascript using the following Javascript code:

```
jwplayer("video").setup({
  file: `//content.jwplatform.com/videos/${media_id}.mp4`
});
```

This loads jwplayer in the lightbox, but no video loads, and the network tab indicates:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/undefined
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:62367
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Request-Id:f1dbbdef-0b60-4eaa-985a-a2eeac47f5bd
X-Runtime:0.196027
X-Web-Console-Mount-Point:/__web_console
X-Web-Console-Session-Id:f94ff88241bbde670a99c01d5fdd9837
```

I have no idea what's happening here.  The video exists, and I know the code is correct to embed the video.  It worked just fine using the iFrame, but I need to use the Javascript API to have exposure to all the methods.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you use single quotes or backticks for your setup object?

Comment: @MarkNijboer I used backticks because it's a template string

Comment: @MarkNijboer I should also add, if I console.log the template string and goto the URL, the video loads fine.

Comment: have you tried this with quotes vs. backticks?